# How to reduce extra space in pdf

Tags: floats, pdf

I am trying to draw using this code. I use `latex abc.tex`. Then `dvipdf abc.dvi`. Problem is 
there is extra space in final pdf. How to tackle this?

```
\documentclass{article}
 \usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{pstricks}
 \usepackage{epsfig,pstricks}
 \usepackage{pst-grad} % For gradients
 \usepackage{pst-plot} 
\begin{document}

\scalebox{1} % Change this value to rescale the drawing.
{
\begin{pspicture}(0,-3.4748354)(7.22,3.48)
\psline[linewidth=0.04cm,shadow=true,doubleline=true,doublesep=0.12](0.02,3.3)(5.12,3.38)
\psline[linewidth=0.04cm,shadow=true,doubleline=true,doublesep=0.12](0.0,3.32)(0.32,-1.7)
\psline[linewidth=0.04cm,shadow=true](1.78,-3.38)(6.38,-3.06)
\psline[linewidth=0.04cm](2.14,-1.82)(7.2,-1.0)
\end{pspicture} 
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you please add an image of the pdf with the extra spacing?  Otherwise, all who want to help have to produce the pdf and guess which space you are referring to.  Thanks!

Comment: what do you mean by "extra space"  you are producing a single page (US Letter sized) pdf file, so there is necessarily space unless you make the tikzpicture exactly the same size. (unrelated but don't use epsfig package, that was written in 1993 as a compatibility layer for documents that were old then, no reason to use it in new documents)

Comment: Use `\documentclass{standalone}` instead of `\documentclass{article}`?